# Send mail from a Gmail catch all address

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, smtp

I just recently set up Google Apps (Standard) on my domain, and I have a catch-all e-mail address on it that I pull e-mail from locally, so I can easily receive e-mail to `anything@example.com`. Now I want it to work in reverse - I want to be able to send from any arbitrary address on my domain, by just including a `From: foo@example.com` header with my message. Unfortunately Gmail will rewrite the header to use whichever e-mail address I authenticated as.

Since `foo@example.com` doesn't actually exist (the incoming e-mails to it are caught by the catch-all, so there's no need to make an actual `foo` account), I can't authenticate as it; I have to authenticate as my catch-all address, and then the e-mail shows up as sent from that address regardless of the `From` header. Gmail *does* support adding additional valid 'From' addresses (in Settings -> Accounts) but I don't want to do that every time I have a new `whatever@example.com` I want to send from.

Is there a way to tell Gmail/Google Apps "I control all e-mail from `example.com`, as long as the 'From' address is on that domain just leave it alone"?

Comment: Have you tried adding a secondary domain?

Comment: @Cawas What do you mean?

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295

Comment: @Cawas Ah. I haven't done that; how would it help?

Comment: check my answer. maybe you should re-word your question title. and sorry for being so late! (blame on [SE notification system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40927/how-do-you-do-to-keep-track-of-notifications))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this at this time.

Your only option using Gmail's interface is to add the address as a "Send mail as" address.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's just not yet possible to "delegate whole domain" on gmail.

But [you can do it](http://lifehacker.com/#!314574/turn-thunderbird-into-the-ultimate-gmail-imap-client) using a [IMAP client](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77662) such as [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/):

> **Better multiple identity and signature management**. Set up multiple "identities" in Thunderbird with email address-specific signatures, which you can't do in web-based Gmail. Hit the "Manage Identities" button in your Account Preferences dialog. The various identities you choose will be available as a dropdown in the From: field in new messages, just like in web-based Gmail. You can also create and automatically attach a vCard to your outgoing messages on a per-identity basis with T-bird, and choose to compose your messages as HTML or plain text per identity, too.

---

About your other unintended question that I accidentally took as the actual question before:

> Is there a way to tell Gmail/Google
>   Apps "I control all e-mail from
>   example.com, as long as the from
>   address is on that domain just leave
>   it alone"?

Yes there is. Just add a [domain alias](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295)!

It will behave just like you expect: it points everything from the alias to the main and makes all of them work seamlessly together.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I only have one domain, I just want to be able to send e-mail from any account on that domain regardless of the account I authenticated as. There's no second domain I need to alias

Comment: Oh, my bad again @Michael! Clearly I didn't understand your question before. I'll edit the answer but I can't think of anyway to do that within google apps.

Comment: "Let it be" doesn't work when you're trying to convince the mailing list server that you're really you.

Comment: @Andre true. Sometimes I'm in the wrong mood to answer questions, and I don't even smoke pot!

Comment: You can't do this with plain Thunderbird either: you still have to create all those identities before using them. The Virtual Identity addon solves that however. Shame Gmail doesn't...